# Why is our "!top10" command not displaying the users properly?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to figure out what is going on with the "!top10" command of our bot. The guy that made the bot is no longer in touch, and he stopped hosting it. I was able to add the source files to GitHub at https://github.com/tye-beach/AventusInviteBot and got the bot back online. However, some functionality seems to be missing.

Could someone help me figure out why the command "!top10" isn't displaying the users properly? It seems to come back with an empty array as you can see in the picture located here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dwAv2VwTjRmgL7QhlbNiMIYE5Rt3BmLi/view

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the specific error that happens when the command is ran. At least, please also give the code of that specific command.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is using an outdated version of discord.py, v0.16.11, that isn't supported anymore. You should look into [migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).

The [default data](https://github.com/tye-beach/AventusInviteBot/blob/master/utils/data.py) that this bot seems to use is empty, and [if `server` is not set, it never loads the invite data](https://github.com/tye-beach/AventusInviteBot/blob/master/cogs/roles_management.py#L83-L84).